# this particular d3 click event not working on Safari but does on Chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cross-browser

My d3 code works for Chrome but not in Safari. I can't pinpoint what the underlying issue is, but the map does not recolor upon mouse click.

Here is a live demo: http://jbk1109.github.io/tennisMapWithPlayersListOnHover.html

```
/*
Draw the intial map
*/
var coloredWorldMap = g.selectAll("path")
      .data(countries)
      .enter()  
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class",function(d){

        return d.name
        // console.log(d)
      })
      .attr("fill","#ddd")
      coloredWorldMap.on('mouseover',tip.show)
      .on('mouseout',tip.hide)
      .on('click', function(d){
        drawBarChart(d)
      })


/*
Recolor the map when a nation on the map is clicked.
*/
function drawBarChart(d){
        selectCountryName = event['path'][0]['__data__']['name']
        selectCountry = d.id    

        countryArray = d3.values(tennis).filter(function(d){
            return d.COUNTRY_ID == selectCountry
        })

/*
1. Select existing bars
2. Need the data array of existing bars.
2. remove the data.
3. remove the bar (the svg element)

*/
console.log(countryArray)
  var addRect = d3.select('g.nations').selectAll('.countryRect')
                  .data(countryArray)

                  addRect.exit().remove()

              addRect.enter()
              .append('rect')

              addRect.transition().duration(650)
              .attr({
                          x: function(d,i){ 
                                return(xScale(d.DATE))
                                // return (rectWidth(d.DATE)) 
                              },
                          y: function(d){ 
                             return (rectHeight + 50) - heightScale(d.COUNT) 
                          },
                          width: function(d){ 
                                return (width-150)/yearArray.length
                                // return rectWidth.rangeBand()
                              },
            height: function(d){ 
                return heightScale(d.COUNT)
              },
            fill: 'steelblue'
        }).attr('class','countryRect')
```